Registering Laravel Middleware without make it global
I'm new in laravel and I confused to how can I register middleware without making it global. in the documentation I only found it to be registered like this (bootstrap\app.php):

this resulting every routes I go was applied with AdminCheck middleware. meanwhile I only want login routes to be applied. also with the laravel breeze there is 'auth' middleware but I can't find the code definition anywhere in the folder structure. can someone explain? thx

Here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#middleware-aliases

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@IMSoP may I ask why?

@excound My comment is a link to an FAQ page dedicated to answering that question.

Route::get('/', function () {
  // ...
})->middleware([First::class, Second::class]);

Check the official doc for more information.

I just realized I only just need to call it away to use it. thx
